# Backbone.js troubles receiving AJAX response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, backbone.js

I'm having troubles catching a response from Rails controller upon saving a model. I can see that the XHR response is generated in the Network tab of Chrome's devtools, but `success` or `error` functions don't fire. I suspect that this is a consequences of forcing post method and different url directly in the view, but I'm not sure, maybe I've messed up some syntax. Here's the snippet of the the save function in coffee:

```
save: (user_id) =>
    model = @model
    if $(".task").val()
        @$el.find(".task").each ->
            model.set
                body: @value
                user_id: user_id
                task_title_id: model.id
            return
        model.save null, type: 'post', url: '/tasks',
            success: (model, response) ->
                console.log 'tasks saved!'
            error: (model, response) ->
                console.log "error! ", response.responseText
    else
        console.log 'nothing to save'
```

and compiled JS:

```
save = function(user_id) {
    var model;
    model = this.model;
    if ($(".task").val()) {
      this.$el.find(".task").each(function() {
        model.set({
          body: this.value,
          user_id: user_id,
          task_title_id: model.id
        });
      });
      return model.save(null, {
        type: 'post',
        url: '/tasks'
      }, {
        success: function(model, response) {
          return console.log('tasks saved!');
        },
        error: function(model, response) {
          return console.log("error! ", response.responseText);
        }
      });
    } else {
      return console.log('nothing to save');
    }
  };
```

Trivia: I have to generate a new `Task` view for each existing `TasktTitle` and then submit these new `Tasks` to the server. Being very new to the Backbone I couldn't come up with a better idea other than render `TaskTitles` collection and add input field for each `TaskTitle` view and then force `post` method and `/tasks` url on save. It does feel quite dirty, but it works as expected with the exception of catching the response, which is a crucial part because there is more logic happens on success\error.

Comment: try this `model.save(...).always(function() { console.log(arguments) })` - what does it say? By the way your save should already be a post, unless your model already has an ID.

Comment: Why did you call `model.save` with `null`?

Comment: @LeshaOgonkov, yes it's exactly the case. I was doing long chain of asynchronous saves prior to this one and I wasn't passing any arguments so I had to use `null` because otherwise callbacks didn't fire and I automatically passed `null` here as well, even though I do pass an arguments. Thanks.

Comment: @LeshaOgonkov although it appears that if I don't pass `null` or `{}` as a first parameter to the save function, then Backbone initiates `put` method and initial `url`. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @DominicTobias, it yields `Cannot read property 'always' of undefined`. My save is `put` because I call save from already existing view - `TaskTitle` , I just reshape the `TaskTitle` model into `Task` model to fit expectations of the Rails controller. And then I need to pass `/tasks` url and force `post` method, which is works, but no success doesn't fire.